# Transform list of occurences into map

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following interface for a coordinate:

```
interface Coordinate {
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
}
```

I will also have an array of such coordinates, example:

```
0:{lat: 51.95, lng: 20.42}
1:{lat: 51.95, lng: 20.42}
2:{lat: 52, lng: 20.45}
3:{lat: 52, lng: 20.45}
```

My question is,

How can i transform a list with occurences into  a map such that:

Map<Coordinate, number> with Coordinate being the coordinate (no duplicates) and the number being how many times such coordinate occured in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a lot simpler to transform the coordinates to a string as a key and back:

```
const map = new Map<Coordinate, number>([...data.reduce((map, coord) => {
    return map.set(coordToKey(coord), (map.get(coordToKey(coord)) ?? 0) + 1);
}, new Map<string, number>()).entries()].map(([key, value]) => [keyToCoord(key), value]));
```

This is because when using objects as keys in maps, it is by reference, so the "same" objects won't map to the same values. [Here](https://tsplay.dev/WKRg8m) you can see that it won't work by default; you'll have to add logic to check if the coordinate already exists, which is very inefficient.

As for the keys, here I have chosen to use a comma to separate the values:

```
const coordToKey = (coord: Coordinate) => `${coord.lat},${coord.lng}`;
const keyToCoord = (key: string) => {
    const [lat, lng] = key.split(",").map(Number);

    return { lat, lng };
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w1p08W)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, would it be possible to introduce a custom comparator in order to avoid the string conversion?

Comment: Natively no, that's why I suggested using some sort of conversion to a usable key.

Comment: Ok, and how could i solve "' new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7009) " problem?

Comment: You might want to ask a new question with the new context this error is in.